# Вопрос по Сессиям

Tags: php

Как правильно разлогинить юзера по кнопке Выход ?
Через `session_destroy` или `session_unset`

P.S читал про оба варианта..но так и не понял, какую стоит использовать

Comment: Зависит от того, как сессии участвуют в логине пользователя. Если вы в сессию просто сохраняете id пользователя, и потом проверяете этот id, то подойдёт session_unset|unset($_SESSION['userId']) (сессия останется, но она будет пустой, как у анонимного пользователя).

Comment: А почему при использовании session_destroy сбрасываются все сессии, а не та, которая использовала нужную  страницу ? На странице только session_destroy()

Comment: Потому, что сессии - это не куки =) Чтобы удалить определенные сессии, используйте `unset($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['login']);`

Comment: @CryEngineV-FlowGraph вам надо разобраться как это работает (это несложно). Вот тут например можно почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/437972/